# How to get text of selected elements in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to extract several forum posts by using the standard XPath method:

`response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "Message userContent")]')`

That one returns a complete list of comments as wished.

But once I include `//text()` or `string(...)` the length of the list jumps up to 100 or 150 items, which makes it impossible to grasp or to iterate over the list and join it with other data like author or the date...

`normalize-space(...)` only returns the first comment.

It has to do something with all the new lines and breaks in the html code but at this stage I have no idea how to handle these.

Would `string-join(...[normalize-space()])` be an option here?

Comment: Share HTML code for the same along with desired output and mentioned XPath expressions with implementation of `text()`, `string()`, `normalize-space()`...

Answer (score 1):

**Realize what each XPath is selecting:**

1. `.//div[contains(@class, "Message userContent")]` selects `div` elements.
2. `.//div[contains(@class, "Message userContent")]//text()` selects all text node descendants of those `div` elements.
3. `normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class, "Message userContent")])` in XPath 1.0 takes the space-normalized string value of the first such `div` element.
4. `normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class, "Message userContent")])` in XPath 2.0 is a runtime error when `normalize-space()` is passed a sequence.

**If you want to get the string values of each such `div`:**

- **XPath 1.0:** Iterate over the selected `div` elements in the hosting
  language and separately take the string value.
- **XPath 2.0:** Append `/string()` to the XPath.

Comment: Thanks for the overview kj! I think the last part helped. I need to figure out the iteration part and how to take the string values out of the list.

The text is directly placed in the div elements. <div class="Message userContent">...blablabla...</div>

Comment: You can get a list of the *immediate child* text nodes via the XPath in #2 but with `/text()` rather than `//text()` at the end.  If there's no markup under the selected `div` elements, then perhaps this list of text nodes will suffice for your purpose.